# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with 0 value

Tags: php, mysql, null, key, duplicates

I've a big problem that I cannot solve.

I've got a form that insert some data into a mysql db. If I'll insert a duplicate key some fields are gonna be updated. But if the form contains empty data, the query will not touch old data.
Next query works, but if I insert "0" the query doesn't upgrade the row with new value (in this case "0"), with others numbers it works.

This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO booking_prices (Data, Room, Disponibilita) 
VALUES ($data, $room, $_POST['Disponibilita']) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Disponibilita = IF(VALUES(Disponibilita) <> '', VALUES(Disponibilita), Disponibilita)
```

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting zonked by MySQL's auto type conversion:

```
> select 0 = '', 0 <> '';
+--------+---------+
| 0 = '' | 0 <> '' |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       0 |
+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note how both tests actually succeed. `0` does equal `''`.

If you're allowing numerics into a text-type field, you should probably do some stricter testing:

```
> select BINARY 0 = '', BINARY 0 <> '';
+---------------+----------------+
| BINARY 0 = '' | BINARY 0 <> '' |
+---------------+----------------+
|             0 |              1 |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Then why compare it against a string (`''`)?

Comment: How I can check if the value inserted in the form are not equal to empty value?

Comment: You're directly inserting $_POST values into yoru query, so you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and if that post field really is totally empty (string length 0), your query will look like `(data, room, )` (note the blank spot for disponibilita) and be a syntax error.

Comment: No, actually I check it previously, I post that query for example. If the string is empty $disponibilita = 'NULL', so I've changed it into Disponibilita = IF(VALUES(Disponibilita) <> NULL, VALUES(Disponibilita), Disponibilita),

Comment: `if (length(VALUES(disponsibilita)) = 0, ...)` would probably be better. a truly "empty" value would have a zero-length.

Comment: when I run this query: 
INSERT INTO booking_prices VALUES ('2014-08-01', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '1')
, ('2014-08-01', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '', '', '', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY Disponibilita = IF(length(VALUES(Disponibilita)) <> 0, VALUES(Disponibilita), Disponibilita)
the first row is set to zero (it has to keep old data, not set 0) and the second is set to "20" (ok, true) because i've insert in the form only "20", the other form fields are empty. Disponibilita is the 10th field.

Comment: You cannot compare a NULL value with anything else, because NULL is neither equal nor unequal to everything (including itself). The only way to check if a value is NULL is to use the MySQL function `ISNULL()`.